# Git - Get the version of a library from the url

Tags: git

Suppose I know that a swift library is located at a given url, such as https://github.com/Peter-Schorn/Swift_Utilities. Is there a way to get the latest version **tag** of the library without downloading it first?

Comment: I’m trying to parse “Is there a way to get the latest version of the library without downloading it first?” Can you explain the difference between “get” and “download”?

Comment: Oh, I see! Maybe “get” means “learn” or “discover” a version _number_. Well, what I usually do is publish that information in the code itself. Typically I keep a History file too.

Comment: There's no inherent concept of version in Git. You need to know how the repository maintainer *exposes* versions.

Comment: Sorry for the confusing phrasing @matt. What I meant was I want to retrieve the latest version *tag*, not the library itself.

Comment: If you make this a Swift package it will have a version number in the Json file and clients will be able to update automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that all of the versions of the library are specified by tags, you can use `git ls-remote` to read the tags and process the latest version:

```
$ git ls-remote https://github.com/Peter-Schorn/Swift_Utilities.git 'refs/tags/*' | \
    grep -v '{}' | tail -n1 | sed 's!.*refs/tags/!!'
2.0.7
```

Note that you may want to use a better sort function than the last item lexicographically, but that's left as an exercise to the reader.

If you want anything more complex (like the latest version on a given branch or non-tagged releases), then you'll either need to clone the repository or use a suitable API for the site you're looking at.

Comment: That's assuming that tags are *only* used for versions.

Comment: Sure, that's another limitation here, as is the fact that some people use leading `v` and some don't.

Comment: I discovered that doesn't work for zsh. I had to switch to bash to get it to work.

Comment: I use zsh, and it does indeed work.  If you have the shell option enabled that errors out when a glob pattern doesn't match, then you need to quote `refs/tags/*`.  But I gave a POSIX sh command, and it works in a standard POSIX or Debian sh environment.

Comment: How do I find out if I have the shell option enabled that errors out when a glob pattern doesn't match? Also how exactly do I quote `refs/tags/*`? Where do I place the quotation marks? And why did I get the error `no matches found: refs/tags/*` when I used zsh, but not for bash?

Comment: I've places appropriate quotation marks to placate zsh.  The problematic option is `badpattern`, and you can see its setting with `set -o | grep badpattern`.  You got the error because zsh realized that `refs/tags/*` didn't match any files on the system, and instead of leaving it as it is, like POSIX specifies, the `badpattern` option causes the shell to abort the command.

Comment: It's getter to quote it anyway. You *intended* for the pattern to be passed literally to `git`, so why take the chance that the shell might expand it?